# Can I make my own SO T-Shirt?

Tags: discussion

Does Stack Overflow (Stack Exchange rather) officially allow me to print out the SO Logo and put it on a T shirt or Jersey?

I live in Germany and I would like one, but unfortunately I couldn't find a place where they sell those, so I thought maybe I can make my own.

Would SE consider this Trademark violation or copyright infringement?

To clarify: I do not intend on selling those, personal use only.

Comment: [MSE dup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244564/280467) (the answer is yes since it's for personal use).

Comment: I've simply chosen to pin a printout of my avatar to my office's  door. So my colleagues will know, when they meet me ;-) ...

Comment: If I see you wearing it in the meat, I will tag your back with a big downvote arrow;)

Comment: @MartinJames Im sure I'll not be visiting the UK in some time, so if you want to do that, you'll have to come to germany :)

Comment: @Magisch  I have been know to visit Berlin, Frankfurt, Hamburg.